# Constraints not showing properly when applying rounded corners to UIView (only on iPhone XS Max & +Versions)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I'm rounding a UIView with this function:

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someUIView.roundCorners([.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 20)            
    }
```

This works as expected but when testing on iPhone XS Max and All Plus models constraints get messed up, but only on the left side of the screen.

I cant figure out why, i think it has something to do with how the rounded corners function applies a layer on the view beacause when i remove the rounded corners layout is fine even on those iPhone models, or maybe it has to do w/ margins? Idk but i'd really appreciate if someone could help me out w/ this one.

[Image so you can appreciate the problem (XS, XSMax, 7, 7+)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRKul.png)

Comment: How did you set your constraints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `UIBezierPath` using `self.bounds` *before* the view is laid out.

Add this to your custom `UIView` class:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
     self.roundCorners([.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 20)
}
```

and remove the call from your view controller's `viewDidLoad()` function.